# Tailwind CSS applying media queries in wrong order after navigating back in NextJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm working on a site using Next JS (App router) and Tailwind CSS, I'm running into a bug I can't find any information about online.

I'm using media queries to swap between my "mobile" and "desktop" view.
This works as intended when I first navigate to the page, like so:

It's a mobile first approach, so my code is laid out like this:

```
<div className="flex flex-col sm:flex-row">
    <...>
</div>
```

[Intended Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3nd3.png)
[Working as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEyK1.png)

This works as intended, and it is put to Flex Row as my screen size is wide enough.

However, if I start on a different page then navigate back to my home page, (Or navigate away from the home page then go back) then Tailwind CSS seems to be applying my styles in the wrong order - Or more specifically, it seems to be duplicating the mobile style in some way? There is an additional style that wasn't there before.

[Not intended design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl0jH.png)
[Not working as intended, now it's in "mobile mode" even though my screen size is large enough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34TO9.png)

To clarify:

Starting at /, the design works as intended.
Starting at /create, then navigating to /, the design has the issue.
Starting at /, navigating to /create, then back to /, the design has the issue.

In testing:

I tried setting up a new project with just two simple pages which link to each other, and the issue was not reproducible.

I've ensured that all my packages are up to date. This occurs in both dev & production mode.

I've made minimal changes to my tailwind configuration file, just adding

```
darkMode: "class",
```

So not sure what is causing this issue.

Thanks!